# How can I change default domain in an OTRS installation?

Tags: otrs

I want to attach new domain to otrs. 
I installed otrs on VPS with CentOS 6
I have the newest version OTRS.

Comment: Could you share what you've tried?

Comment: I try create iFrame to domain.com/otrs/index.pl but iFrame doesnt work.
I try to create redirect 301 in httaccess